# is it possible to restore file history (or the repo) from the local .svn directory if my repo has been damaged/deleted

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My apologies for such a long post.

Lets say my hard drive died and my actual svn repository is irrecoverable (its gone). Is there a way to restore file history (or the repo) from the local .svn directories if my repo has been damaged/deleted?  I do have a backup copy of key sections of the repository but it is only the local .svn directories and the *.svn-base and *.svn-work inside them. Is it possible to do anything with the .svn folder or am i pretty much hosed?

I do have the latest revisions 'head' of various sub-trees, but i was just curious how much info can be recovered from the local copies of the .svn folder?

i did come across this post 'http://leshazlewood.com/2008/03/13/subversion-failure-recovery-without-a-backup/'  but am wondering what i can actually extract from my local .svn directory... and if history is indeed lost - why bother and not just create a new repo with the current 'head' release for the various sub-trees that i have locally?

Should i just nuke the .svn folder and start over or is there something I might be able to recover from them?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to restore file history (or the repo) from the local
>   .svn directories if my repo has been damaged/deleted?

No, the [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) contains a certain repository state / snapshot, but no version history. You should consider implementing a decent backup solution for your repositories.